# Twitter OAuth - Incorrect signature errors - what have I missed?

Tags: ruby, curl, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have read the [page on implementing OAuth that Twitter have written](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth). I've registered my app, it will only access my account, so I skip all the request token stuff. I have, from the ["Your apps"](http://dev.twitter.com/apps) page:

- consumer token
- consumer token secret
- access token
- access token secret

I write some ruby code and test its output against [Beginner’s Guide to OAuth](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iv-signing-requests/) (suggested reading in the Twitter docs). I get the same output, i.e. the signature, the base string and the Authorization headers are identical.

However, when I connect to the Twitter Rest API and try the [verify credentials command](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554689/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-account%C2%A0verify_credentials) the response is invariably "Incorrect signature".

I try using different code (very similar to mine) from [a gist by erikeldridge on github](https://gist.github.com/383159) but it doesn't work either. Instead of connecting via cURL (using the [curb library](http://curb.rubyforge.org/)) I use Net/Http - same error response is returned.

I change over to using the [OAuth gem](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/). It uses Net/Http to connect. Same error response comes back.

Verify credentials isn't the only command I've tried to use in the API, but they all give the same error, whether it's GET or POST, requires extra params or not. I've been using the Search API successfully using the curb library without problems so I don't think it's the connection method.

What might I do to fix this?

Ruby 1.9.2; cURL 7.21.2; oauth 0.4.4; curb 0.7.8; json 1.4.6; OSX 10.6.5;

Comment: Fixed - I regenerated the Consumer key and secret on the Twitter site and it started working. I've no idea why the previous set didn't work, perhaps they could provide more detailed error messages? But I'm happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed - I regenerated the Consumer key and secret on the Twitter site and it started working. I've no idea why the previous set didn't work - the code was solid (works all the time now) and the details were correct. Perhaps they (Twitter) could provide more detailed error messages? But I'm happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though your application is only accessing your data, you can't simply 'skip the request token stuff'. The request token is integral to the OAuthentication process.

Summarised, the 3 main parts of the OAuth process are as follows:

1. Get Request Token Key and Request Token Secret
2. Use Request Token to authorise application to access your data. This will provided the user(you) with a PIN
3. Use the PIN to exchange the Request Token and Secret for an Access Token and Secret.

A more detailed OAuthentication flow can be found [here](http://www.snipe.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/diagram-560x411.png).

Comment: Thanks. I did the PIN bit anyway, but the Twitter docs say that you can skip it if your application will only access your account, and they therefore provide you with the access token and secret from the Your Account page - so why would I need to run the request?

Comment: Apologies- I did not realise that Twitter provided an Access Token and Secret in a single user case. You are correct, you shouldn't need to run through the full process. 

The only thing I can suggest is to double check how you are hashing your signature base - I had a nightmare with this when first using OAuth. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the help Stephen. Infuriating as it is to hear you've done things right but still not have a solution, it's helpful to push things somewhere else (and confirms that you're not crazy!:) I reset the keys on the Twitter dev site and now it works - no idea why but it works! Thanks again.